# Angular Material mat-spinner custom color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, spinner

Does anyone know how can I change mat-spinner color in Angular Material?
Overriding css doesn't work. I tried changing color in material files but they can only be imported, I can't change anything there. 
I want it to be my custom color, not color from prebiult-themes.

Comment: Hi, can you post an example on how you tried to override the CSS?

Answer (score 57):

Use this code for  **  < mat-spinner >** add this code in your **.css** file

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
stroke: #3fb53f;
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, if you are displaying spinner in some internal component then one can use the same CSS, mentioned here, by prefixing with ':host /deep/...'. Like ":host /deep/.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
stroke: #3fb53f;
}

Comment: Is it OK to use this in production? Seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Hi, can we update the spinner color dynamically (eg : selected color should be updated from picker) ?

Answer (score 43):

This answer will work for those who're looking for a flexible solution in Angular 4 / 6 / 7. If you wan't to change the color of a mat-spinner at a component level, you'll need to use the `::ng-deep` selector. Knowing this, the solution is quite easy.

- In your html file:

```html
    <div class="uploader-status">
        <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
```

- In your css / scss file:

```css
    .uploader-status ::ng-deep .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
        stroke: #000000;
    }
```

Notice that the `.uploader-status` css class encapsulates the component. You could just use `::ng-deep` without using a class but then whatever changes you're doing to the mat-spinner will appear in other areas of the application. [Check this to learn more](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459).

Comment: Funcionou pra mim!

Comment: Saved my life today.

Answer (score 18):

**Easy Fix!**

Add custom css rules inside **styles.css** instead of component.css file

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #2A79FF!important;
}
```

Comment: For me it also didn't work on component level, but it works fine in the global.css.

Comment: Tried everything else. This is the only method that worked for me. Added it to my styles.css (after @import theme) rather than component css.

Comment: This makes all spinners white, right? Wouldn't consider that an easy fix. You could however add an outer class so this only applies to spinners inside an element with that class.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to mess around with the global css and need a way to set the spinner to different colors in different areas of your app, I would strongly recommend to create a directive for it.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[customSpinner]"
})
export class CustomSpinnerDirective implements AfterViewInit{

  @Input() color: string;

  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(!!this.color){
      const element = this.elem.nativeElement;
      const circle = element.querySelector("circle");
      circle.style.stroke = this.color;
    }
  }

}
```

Then the spinner should work like this:

```
<mat-spinner diameter="22" customSpinner color="#fff"></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: Clean, no use of ng-deep, multiple colors for different part of the app. Perfect.

Answer (score 14):

To your .css/.scss component file style add (it will works locally - in component only)

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {   
    stroke: #bada55;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! adding :host ::ng-deep made it work for me.

Comment: where did you find out about `:host ::ng-deep` ?

Answer (score 11):

`.mat-mdc-progress-spinner { --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: white; }`

This worked for me using Angular 15.

Comment: Provide a clear and concise overview of what the code does and why it is relevant. This can help other users understand the purpose and context of the code, and how it fits into the overall solution.

Comment: Angular Materials 15 introduced a new version of Progress Spinner (making the previous one 'legacy') so if you want to switch to the new Progress Spinner you need to use this instead of the other answers.

Comment: work perfectly in angular 17

Answer (score 10):

mat-spinner html code :

`<mat-spinner color="accent" diameter="20" class="loading"></mat-spinner>`

And now sass code :

```
.mat-spinner {
    ::ng-deep circle {
        stroke: #33dd82;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Color is build in.

Theming
The color of a progress-spinner can be changed by using the color property. By default, progress-spinners use the theme's primary color. This can be changed to 'accent' or 'warn'.

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview

example

```
<mat-spinner color="warn"></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: Extremely limited, what if you need a one off like white?

Comment: The question is literally how to set a _custom_ color.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key here is that is must be in the GLOBAL `styles.css` file.  The below solution does work if placed there (should be the CSS file affected when material was added to the project if added with `ng add`:

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #b68200;
}
```

Of course you could also add classes to the component and specify different selectors if you want distinctly styled spinners.  However, it seems the classes must be in the global CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the game, but this worked well in my `.scss` file today...

```
.parent-element-class {
    ::ng-deep 
    .mat-progress-spinner,
    .mat-spinner {
        circle {
            stroke: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your styles.css file, add...

```css
::ng-deep .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #2A79FF!important;
}
```

As you might have guessed, I have just made a simple modification to [Nitin Wahale's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9233226/nitin-wahale) answer. I have prefixed his answer with `::ng-deep` and it worked in my case as I had the same issue.

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: `::ng-deep` is not recommended and should not be used. It will may have impact on other components and parts of application as well.

Answer (score 2):

By default angular material would give your spinner default color of primary.
You can use 3 colors available in pallet that would be primary, accent, warn.
However, if your needs are of different color please consider anyone of the below options.

1. Easy way(not recommended)
   You can use any of method to override css forcefully mention in other answers. I would recommend using parent class above spinner element if you do not want spinner to be of same color throughout the application.
2. The correct and recommended approach would we to use custom-theme for material. If you already have custom you can just
   do like creating a custom mixin called

   //here $primary-color is the color you want your spinner to be
   @mixin spinner-custom-theme($primary-color, $accent-color, $warn-color) {
   $custom-spinner-theme-primary: mat-palette($primary-color);
   $custom-spinner-theme-accent: mat-palette($accent-color, A200, A100, A400);
   $custom-spinner-theme-warn: mat-palette($warn-color);

   $custom-spinner-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-theme-primary, $custom-theme-accent, $custom-theme-warn);

   @include mat-progress-spinner-theme($custom-spinner-theme);
   }

Now go to file where @include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
is written
and @include your mixin just below the  @include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);

To know more on how to create custom theme you can check this blog [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html)

Answer (score 2):

With css variable:

```
:root {
    --color-spinner: #3f51b5;
}

.mat-mdc-progress-spinner {
    --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: var(--color-spinner);
}
```

Without css variable:

```
.mat-mdc-progress-spinner {
        --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Angular Material 17.0.4

In your HTML file:

```
<mat-spinner [color]="color"></mat-spinner>
```

In your TS file:

```
color: ThemePalette = 'accent';
```

**Do not forget to import ThemePalette inside TS file:**

```
import {ThemePalette} from '@angular/material/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Color, strokeWidth, diameter and title

```
<mat-spinner strokeWidth="24" [diameter]="85" color="warn" title="Tooltip text here"></mat-spinner>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In your css file mention like below:

::ng-deep.mat-progress-spinner circle,.mat-spinner circle {stroke: #f2aa4cff !important;}
```

Here, ::ng-deep will be used to force a style.

!important here what says is that "this is Important",you ignore all other rules and apply this rule.

Comment: When adding an answer to a question that already has eleven answers it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, because without that someone may mistake your answer for a duplicate or even a copy if your change was subtle. Plus you aren't advocating for your answer by explaining how and why it works and why it is the best choice for whatever criteria you think it is best for.

Answer (score 1):

```
:host >>> .mat-mdc-progress-spinner .mdc-circular-progress__determinate-circle,
:host >>> .mat-mdc-progress-spinner .mdc-circular-progress__indeterminate-circle-graphic {
    stroke: #fff !important;
}
```

Add the above code snippet in your styling file and this will help to customise the colour of the **mat-spinner**

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved by doing a custom theme.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Yes. It wasn't until I added it to styles.css after the @import that I got a fix.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<md-progress-circular md-diameter="20px"></md-progress-circular>

md-progress-circular path {
  stroke: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you guys want to customize each spinner on your webpage. You can do it this way:

```
svg .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
  stroke: inherit;
}
```

And now on mat-spinner add class:

```
<mat-spinner class="custom-spinner-color"></mat-spinner>
```

And in css file:

```
.custom-spinner-color {
  stroke: #234188;
}
```

That was what I wanted to achieve. I suppose if you look for this question you probably want the same.

Answer (score 0):

Mat progress spinner custom timer, I changed to 3 different colors based on the value passed to mat spinner. Pls refer : https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples

```
<mat-progress-spinner class="mat-spinner" [color]="progressColor" 
[diameter]="170" [strokeWidth]="14"[mode]="'determinate'" 
[value]="progressLabel">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

Ts file

```
timer: number = TIMER;  // say 60 seconds
progressColor: ThemePalette = 'accent';
timerPercent: number = 0; 
progressLabel: number = 100;

startTimer() {
 this.timer = TIMER;
 this.timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (this.timer <= 0) {
    clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
    this.timerFinish();
  }
  if (this.timer > 0) {
    this.progressColor =
      this.timerPercent > 69
        ? 'warn'
        : this.timerPercent > 49
        ? 'primary'
        : 'accent';
    this.timer--;
    this.timerPercent = (100 * (TIMER - this.timer)) / TIMER;
    this.progressLabel = 100 - this.timerPercent;
  }
 }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is how I do it clean without messing with anything globally:

in my .css

```
::ng-deep .customColorSpinner circle {stroke: #4e1e1e!important;}
```

in my .html

```
<mat-spinner class="customColorSpinner"></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: you should try to avoid using `::ng-deep` since this is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Angular Directive to solve this problem. The directive allows you to set a custom color on the mat-spinner like this:

```
<mat-progress-spinner spinnerColor="#09ff00"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

I have an article [here where I explain this and thoroughly show you how to solve it](https://bullishlife.com/angular-material/change-mat-spinner-color-in-angular-material-using-directives/)

Answer (score 0):

In component.scss where your mat-spinner exists, just add this :

```css
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-progress-spinner {
  --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: #7D469A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using angular 13, I changed the color in this way:

```
<mat-progress-spinner
  color="primary"
  mode="indeterminate"
  value="50">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

Then I defined the .css file for the single component where I need to use it.

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
  stroke: #2aff5c!important;
 }
```

In case you need to reuse it in multiple components, could be a good idea put it in the global css file, in that case you probably don't need to specify the ::ng-deep.

Answer (score 0):

in the latest versions the solution no longer works.

Now to change the color you have to do :

```css
::ng-deep .mdc-circular-progress__indeterminate-container circle, .mdc-circular-progress__circle-clipper circle {
  stroke: #757575!important;
}
```