# Change color of mat-spinner

Tags: angular-material, angular6

How to change color of mat-spinner
i tried this but doesn't work

**Html**

```
<mat-spinner [color]="red" ></mat-spinner>
<mat-spinner [color]="#ffffff" ></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material mat-spinner custom color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786027/angular-material-mat-spinner-custom-color)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code worked for me :

**scss**

```
.mat-spinner-color::ng-deep circle{
stroke: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-spinner [diameter]="25" class="mat-spinner-color"></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: Ng-deep is to be deprecated as discussed here. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/ I would advice against this.

Answer (score 4):

The color property only accepts the values `primary`, `accent` and `warning`. These are colors that correspond to the Material Design theme used in your project.

```
<mat-spinner color="primary"></mat-spinner>
```

If you want to override this with a custom color add the following css in a **global style sheet**:

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
  stroke: /* color */
}
```

### Note

View encapsulation prevents the styles from working when placed in a component style sheet.

Comment: Place it in the global styles, style sheet, i.e. `styles.(s)css`. View encapsulation messes with material styles sometimes.

Comment: that's what worked for me .mat-spinner-color::ng-deep circle{
    stroke: #FFFFFF !important;
}  <mat-spinner [diameter]="25" class="mat-spinner-color"></mat-spinner>

Comment: Yeah that one works through view encapsulation, I guess.

Comment: @OmarAMEZOUG are you telling me that my code did not work? Because I tested it.

Comment: I tried your code but doesn't work for me, maybe because i didn't put your code in global css file, but in my case i need to put the code in my component css file

Answer (score 1):

The `color` input accepts three values:

- `primary`: The primary palette of your app
- `warn`: The warn palette of your app
- `accent`: The accent palette of your app

To use hex codes, you can only do it with CSS. I suggest you use the Chrome DevTools to see which CSS classes to target. Note that you should use the `!important` selector as well.

Comment: in DevTools i have this line of code .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #673ab7;
} . i tried this code in my css file but doesn't change the color : .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: #FFFFFF !important;
  }

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me:

**scss**

```
.mat-mdc-progress-spinner{
  --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: #yourColor;
}
```

There was no need to change anything in the html file.