# Cannot change mat-spinner's colour

Tags: angular-material

I know this question has been asked ([Change color of mat-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700871/change-color-of-mat-spinner)) but I was wondering if there's been a solution to not using the deprecated ::ng-deep?

In addition, I've also tried the method suggested in the link but that doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="pending" mode="indeterminate" class="mat-spinner-color"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

**SCSS**

```
.mat-spinner-color::ng-deep circle{
    stroke: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

::ng-deep is not officially deprecated and is contingent upon browsers removing support for it, per `angular.io`, `until then`, meaning is officially deprecated by the browsers, `it should be preferred` over `/deep/` and `>>>` for broader compatibility.

> As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>>
>   and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader
>   compatibility with the tools.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

---

If your preference is to avoid ::ng-deep you will need to apply your modifications for the `mat-spinner` to the root `styles.css` in your project

in `styles.css`

```
.orange-spinner circle{
  stroke:orange !important;
}
```

add class

```
<mat-spinner class="orange-spinner"></mat-spinner>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czd4zq?embed=1&file=styles.css

---

**Please note:**

Per `UmutEsen` comment below, the correct solution is to setup a theme and leverage the `color` input on the `mat-spinner`.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: While this is a quick solution that works, one may also consider implementing a custom theme to override default colours of Material theme https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: @UmutEsen is correct, the correct solution is to setup a theme and leverage the `color` input on the class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up using ::ng-deep and can confirm that it works. My issue ended being improper nesting in my scss.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used `::ng-deep` and it is still working.

below worked for me.

```
    .mat-mdc-progress-spinner::ng-deep {
    --mdc-circular-progress-active-indicator-color: #006FB9;
   }
```