# Angular Material Spinner color primary not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have included mat-spinner in my html:

```html
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>                   ---> spinner in white color, so not seen
<mat-spinner color="primary"></mat-spinner>   ---> spinner in white color, so not seen
<mat-spinner color="warn"></mat-spinner>      ---> red spinner
<mat-spinner color="accent"></mat-spinner>    ---> yellow spinner
```

In the first and second case, the spinner is displayed in white color

I have MatProgressSpinnerModule in my module file

styles.scss has:

```js
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Then why is the primary color white?

Comment: There's no option for `color="primary"` for `mat-spinner`. Refer to this link - https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview#theming

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710400/6536335

Comment: You can see the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnvpkebnopa?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-configurable-example.ts)

Comment: Where did you import the MatProgressSpinnerModule?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht in the component's module ts

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for reproduction? Are you sure you are using `mat-spinner` and not `mat-progress-spinner`?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht please see the updated question. It is actually displayed in white, so it is not seen

Comment: Are you overriding the css `stroke` property by any chance?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht yes it was getting overriden in styles.scss as `.mat-progress-spinner circle {
  stroke: white;
}`

Answer (score 1):

By default, **progress-spinners** use the theme's primary color. This can be changed to `accent` or `warn`.

You might override `stroke` stylesheet in your theme's css.

Refer to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710400/6536335).